# How to set an Event to the Button control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I'm trying to set  `OnClick-Event` to the `asp:Button` control. I already tried to `double-click` the button also from `Properties-Window >> Events >> Actions` but these doesn't work. Any idea why would i face such thing and how to solve it ?

Comment: double click on the same button on design mode - the most simple that you can do, and visual studio will make the click event for you.

Comment: @Aristos I mentioned that this doesn't work, you didn't even understand my issue, Do you really have to downvote it ?

Comment: When i do that , nothing happens , it should make a method automatically for me , but it doesn't.

Comment: You say that you double click from the properties window - I say, to double click on it.

Comment: @Aristos, i mentioned both things.

Comment: then you have mess up the files - do you have correct setup the aspx file with the aspx.cs file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it manual, eg:

```
<asp:Button id="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save"></asp:Button>
```

and on code behind

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // here place your code for the click event.
}
```

Comment: That what i did when i wasted my time trying to find an answer! but thanks anyway.

Comment: I figured it out. The cause of such thing would happens when the project is not build-able(Have Errors).